# OpenCV Python 3.6.1 SIFT and ORB not found

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently working on detecting feature points for a distorted 2d Bardcode.
Therefore I want to identify the Squares at the edges and than undistore the QR code to read it with pyzbar.

I tried ShiThomasi but I cannot rely on stabil enlightning environment. Therefore, I wanted to use ORB features
`orb = cv2.ORB_create()`
normaly i assume that when I write `orb."command"` and search for a command like detectFeatures or something useful I don't get any Method.

I know that OpenCV shifted SIFT and ORB to the contribution version. However, when I install the contribution Version wheel my cv2 crashed and I had to set up my whole IDE and Python.

Is there any way that I can copy the SIFT and ORB.dll into my site package folder? And where to find them?

WINDOWS10 PYTHON 3.6.1 CV2 all 64Bit.

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm programming in Eclipse :)

Comment: Best way to configure OpenCV is to build it yourself. That way you can customize it to your own needs. If you build it yourself make that `BUILD_NONFREE` is ON. That builds SIFT.

Comment: Have you got a useful link how to do that and where to get the files I need?